# Half of dataframe csv file missing column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a csv file which is continuously updated with new data. The data has 5 columns, however lately the data have been changed to 4 columns. The column that is not present in later data is the first one. When I try to read this csv file into a dataframe, half of the data is under the wrong columns. The data is around 50k entries.

```
df
################################
   0    time   C-3   C-4   C-5   
 ______________________________
   0      1    str    4    5       <- old entries 
   0      1    str    4    5      
   1     str    4     5    Nan     <- new entries
   1     str    4     5    Nan
   1     str    4     5    Nan    

#################################
```

The first column in earlier entries (where value = 0) are not important.

My expected output is the Dataframe being printed with the right values in the right columns. I have no idea on how to add the `0` before the `str` where the `0` is missing. Or reverse, remove the `0`. (since the `0` looks to be a index counter with value starting at 1, then 2, etc.)

Here is how i load and process the csv file at the moment:

```
def process_csv(obj):
    data='some_data'
    path='data/'
    file=f'{obj}_{data}.csv'
    df=pd.read_csv(path+file)
    df=df.rename(columns=df.iloc[0]).drop(df.index[0])
    df = df[df.time != 'time']
    mask = df['time'].str.contains(' ')
    df['time'] = (pd.to_datetime(df.loc[mask,'time'])
                   .reindex(df.index)
                   .fillna(pd.to_datetime(df.loc[~mask, 'time'], unit='ms')))
    df=df.drop_duplicates(subset=['time'])
    df=df.set_index("time")
    df = df.sort_index()

    return df
```

since column `time` should be of type `int`, a missing first column causes `str` values that should end up in `C-3` to end up in column `time` which causes error:
`ValueError: non convertible value str with the unit 'ms'`

Question: How can I either remove the early values from column `0` or add some values to the later entries?

Comment: Since you changed the format of the CSV, it would be reasonable to put all of this new fangled 4 column stuff in a different file. Can you update how the CSV is written to either include a default value in column 0 to conform to the old standard or to write a new file?

Comment: So, the reason why I asked the question is that the best fix is in the code that writes the csv. If you are stuck, something can be hacked. But how about letting us know?

Comment: yeah, so the column `0` appeared when I merged the csv files together. And now when i update it this problem has appeared. However I need all the data in the same file. I download the data (many different files, +200 types) with requests.get and make `df` which i save to the corresponding csv. Are you advising me to add a column to all the df's before they are written to corresponding csv?

Comment: Okay, you have many CSV files, and 200 types... meaning different CSV types? Its best to normalize them somehow instead of just dumping them all into a single aggregate CSV. The point of a CSV is that each column is of a single type. I think you should take those original CSVs and normalize them (add or remove columns so that each column is now in the right place) and then concatenate them into a single dataframe. With 200+ types, that is a huge effort. Do they share anything in common that could be used to normalize with?

Comment: No sorry I meant there are many csv files, csv1,csv2,csv3 which all have their specific structure, columns, values etc. I'm downloading data and updating the data which belongs to the right csv file. With merge i meant that i earlier had many e.g. csv1's which i merged into one csv1, I did the same for all the csv's, I think thats where the `0` column is from. The data in the csv files are ordered, except now when the data is shifted to "to the left" so to say.

Comment: If they "all have their specific structure" that means they are all different and they should not be merged. if they all have the same or simlar structure, that's something else. Lets say there are 5 column CSVs and 4 column CSVs, and you don't care about that first column. You could rewrite the 5 column CSVs into 4 columns then have something that would work for the merge. By the time you build the dataframe, you want all columns in the csv to be of a single type so that pandas data type guessing works.

Comment: Do you still have the original unmerged csv files? If so, why not just load them as separate dataframes, and have the wanted columns concatenated vertically?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding me. The csv's with different structures was not being merged, only the ones with the same structure got merged. But when those were merged i think it added another index column which the new data doesn't have.

Answer (score 0):

If one CSV file contains multiple formats, and these CSV files cannot be changed, then you could parse the files *before* creating data frames.

For example, the test data has both 3- and 4-field records.  The function `gen_read_lines()` always returns 3 fields per records.

```
from io import StringIO
import csv
import pandas as pd

data = '''1,10,11
2,20,21
3,-1,30,31
4,-2,40,41
'''

def gen_read_lines(filename):
    lines = csv.reader(StringIO(filename))
    for record in lines:
        if len(record) == 3:    # return all fields
            yield record
        elif len(record) == 4:  # drop field 1
            yield [record[i] for i in [0, 2, 3]]
        else:
            raise ValueError(f'did not expect {len(records)}')

records = (record for record in gen_read_lines(data))
df = pd.DataFrame(records, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
print(df)

   A   B   C
0  1  10  11
1  2  20  21
2  3  30  31
3  4  40  41
```